# Faucet gets loose and has to be hand tightened every couple of weeks

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink, kitchen-sink

I'm visiting my parents in a few days and need some plumbing help.

They have a faucet in the in their kitchen that was solid for a couple of years, but then suddenly earlier this year it gets loose every couple of weeks or so. Then they have to hand tighten it, and it lasts about 1-2 weeks again. I've done some research online but the underside of their faucet looks a bit different, it's a plastic nut with hand tightening points, not a metal one like I've seen. I was thinking of maybe getting a metal nut and some threadlocker and replacing the plastic one, but I'm definitely not a plumbing expert, I also don't know what removing the plastic one entirely entails, I assume I'll need to remove the line coming in?

[image: faucet]

Comment: It seems like a good idea, but a picture of the nut coming loose will help more.

Comment: I doubt thread locker will be necessary - it's not part of a plumber's standard tool kit. As noted, pics of the actual underside of the faucet will be most instructive.